# Baire's Theorem with locally compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Statement of the theorem:

> If $S$ is either
>
> a) a complete metric space, or
>
> b) a locally compact Hausdorff space,
>
> Then the intersection of every countable collection of dense open subsets of $S$ is dense in $S$.

The idea of the proof is to show that every open set $B$ intersects the countable union of given dense open subsets. Specifically if $\left\{ V_i \right\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is such a collection and $B$ is an arbitrary open set the following recursion is then defined

$$
\begin{array}{l}
B_0 = B \\
\bar{B}_{n} \subset V_n \cap B_{n-1}
\end{array}
$$

Later we define

$$
K = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bar{B}_n
$$

The author at this point states that $K$ isn't empty by compactness.
I cannot really understand why.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space#Formal_definition):

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Most commonly $X$ is called locally compact, if every point $x$ of $X$ has a compact neighbourhood, i.e., there exists an open set $U$ and a compact set $K$, such that ${\displaystyle x\in U\subseteq K}$

I guess this is the definition that we're trying to apply, but I can't figure how exactly we apply it.

Comment: There are  some crucial  facts missing here. With what you have quoted it is not possible to show that $K$ is not empty. Please look at the entire proof.

Comment: The only bit I missed is that, according to the Rudin, $\bar{B}_n$ can be chosen to be compact is this what I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, you missed the most important assumption.

Comment: Another case that works for Baire category theorem: locally countably compact regular space.

Answer (score 5):

$(\overline {B_n})$ is decreasing sequence of nonempty compact sets and hence their intersection is not empty: if it is empty then  complements of  $\overline {B_n}, n=2,3,,$ cover the compact set $\overline {B_1}$. Hence there is a finite sub-cover. But this means $\cap_{n=1}^{N} \overline {B_n} (=\overline {B_N})$ is empty for some $N$, a contradiction.